# Interface fields showing as null in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have an interface with fields.

For example:

```
public interface InterfaceWithFields {
    String field1 = "FIELD_1";
    String field2 = "FIELD_2";
}
```

When I debug the project using Android Studio, sometimes (not everytime) - I try to get the field and it returns null -

```
InterfaceWithFields.field1 /returns null
```

I thought all the time field in interface by default is `public static final` - it means it static at least - so it must be initialized immediately, when class is loaded.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using interfaces like this, at least not from what I have seen in my experience.

Comment: How are you trying to access the field?

Comment: I am trying to access exactly as i write before - InterfaceWithFields.field1  and in debug mode i tried to access through class that implements this interface, it gives same result..

Comment: @zgc7009 it's not that unusual to place constants in interfaces in Java. Eg. Android SDK has some constants in its `DialogInterface` (`BUTTON_POSITIVE`, `BUTTON_NEGATIVE`).

Comment: Like the first comment says, interfaces should simply be contracts with no implementation code so that whoever needs the different functions can decide on what to do. You can store those fields in the implementing classes

Comment: We need a complete example. Those fields are not `final` so the most likely explanation is they're being changed somewhere. Have you tried marking them as `final` and seeing if a compile error occurs somewhere?

Comment: @zgc7009 a common practice - seen as an anti-pattern by some - is even to use interfaces *exclusively* as buckets for constants; this trick allows to conveniently "import" constants into a class by making it implement the interface. Now this hack is sort of shoddy to me, anyway I get to see it often

Comment: @PaulBoddington Interface fields are implicitly static final

Comment: @imps You're right. I'm not thinking today.

Comment: You need to give us more info and accurate info. There are a bunch of reasons the field may be appearing as null.
A bug in the JDK is one of them for ex:
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8078241

Comment: @KonradMorawski I knew that you could have constants in interfaces, particularly those implemented by classes that are meant to be subclassed or instantiated, but never seen a constant bucket. That is interesting, and I have to concur sounds a bit shoddy to me as well :P Thanks for the info though!

Comment: unfortunatelly I dont know how can i give u more accurate info(( i cant place the real code because its a commercial secret and beleive me in strong approximation it looks as code i placed here - if you know any reason why i get that situation tell me pls i will examine it

Comment: This is very odd indeed. The JLS says that "references to constant fields are resolved at compile time". This means that the string `"FIELD_1"` should simply get written into the compiled code (rather than `InterfaceWithFields.field1`). It could be a bug with your compiler.

Comment: I know your question is a simplified version. Does the real version definitely say `field1 = "FIELD_1"` or is it really something like `field1 = someMethodReturningString();`?

Comment: @PeteTrikhin Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes i am using android studio - and this happen during developing android project. The real version of code is - if (someMethod(InterfaceWithFields.field1))    where someMethod take a String as a parameter

Comment: @PeteTrikhin When do you see it as `null`, during debugging or at runtime?

Comment: during debuging and runtime (not  really sure about runtime - but the application behaves as that field was null)

Comment: @zgc7009 yes it feels wrong on semantic level, because it abuses the concept of an interface. It's supposed to represent a contract, and having constants within an interface is fine if these constants make sense *within the context of this interface* (like in that Android SDK example I quoted). It's not different from putting constants in a fully abstract class then. But if the interface has no method signatures, it doesn't represent any meaningful context, because there is no contract. With this hack `SomeClass instanceof InterfaceWithJustConstants` would return true, but what does it *mean*?

Comment: @zgc7009 a more sensible alternative is to use a final class as a container for constants, and then `import static ClassWithConstants.*` allows to use them in another class without repeating the `ClassWithConstants` prefix everywhere. The same on the surface, but more respectful of the conventions behind OOP :)

Answer (score 7):

I think it is a bug in Android Studio debugger.

[image: Screenshot]

In the above image see when you evaluate the field in the evaluator it says that `IConstants.TAG` is `null`. But in the LogCat you can see that it is not actually `null`. It actually has a value of `MyApp` which is printed in the LogCat.

**IConstants.java**

```
public interface IConstants {
    String TAG = "MyApp";
}
```

Comment: Its first time when I hearing about that bug, thanks a lot

Comment: @PeteTrikhin I'm not sure if it has been raised as an issue or not. Its something I found during my development.